# Able to store in IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session - Retrieval is empty

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core

I'm working with an API and using the session feature in .Net Core 2.1 with the standard dependency injection to store and retrieve values in the session store. My issue is that I'm able to set and store string values into the Session.store but when I then try to retrieve those values in another method, the store is empty.

Here is my Startup.cs setting up the IHttpContextAccessor for DI and enabling session storage.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-                // essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        // Configure app settings to inject in other classes.
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        // Services to be injected.
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConstituentsService, ConstituentsService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISessionService, SessionService>();

        // Add MVC.
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Configure session.
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AuthCodeFlowTutorial.Session";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure     the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here is the class I'm using where I'm storing in the session store and then the method right after to retrieve. SetTokens() and TryGetString() respectively.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CHS.SkyApiAuthCodeFlow
{

/// <summary>
/// Sets, gets, and destroys session variables.
/// </summary>
public class SessionService : ISessionService
{
    private const string ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME = "token";
    private const string REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME = "refreshToken";
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Destroys access and refresh tokens from the session.
    /// </summary>
    public void ClearTokens()
    {
        try 
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Remove(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Remove(REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LOGOUT ERROR: " + error.Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return access token, if saved, or an empty string.
    /// </summary>
    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        return TryGetString(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return refresh token, if saved, or an empty string.
    /// </summary>
    public string GetRefreshToken()
    {
        return TryGetString(REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the access and refresh tokens based on an HTTP response.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetTokens(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Dictionary<string, string> attrs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME, attrs["access_token"]);
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME, attrs["refresh_token"]);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return session value as a string (if it exists), or an empty string.
    /// </summary>
    private string TryGetString(string name)
    {
        byte[] valueBytes = new Byte[700];
        bool valueOkay = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(name, out valueBytes);
        if (valueOkay)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBytes);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Below is the `AuthenticationService` that calls on the `SessionService` methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace CHS.SkyApiAuthCodeFlow
{

/// <summary>
/// Contains business logic and helper methods that interact with the authentication provider.
/// </summary>
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{   

    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    private ISessionService _sessionService;

    public AuthenticationService(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, ISessionService sessionService)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        _sessionService = sessionService;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches access/refresh tokens from the provider.
    /// <param name="requestBody">Key-value attributes to be sent with the request.</param>
    /// <returns>The response from the provider.</returns>
    /// </summary>
    private HttpResponseMessage FetchTokens(Dictionary<string, string> requestBody) 
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) 
        {   
            // Build token endpoint URL.
            string url = new Uri(new Uri(_appSettings.Value.AuthBaseUri), "token").ToString();

            // Set request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(_appSettings.Value.AuthClientId + ":" + _appSettings.Value.AuthClientSecret));

            // Fetch tokens from auth server.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestBody)).Result;

            // Save the access/refresh tokens in the Session.
            _sessionService.SetTokens(response);

            return response;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches a new set of access/refresh tokens (from an authorization code).
    /// <param name="code">The authorization code contained within the provider's authorization response.</param>
    /// </summary>
    public HttpResponseMessage ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(string code)
    {
        return FetchTokens(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            { "code", code },
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "redirect_uri", _appSettings.Value.AuthRedirectUri }
        });
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the expired access token (from the refresh token stored in the session).
    /// </summary>
    public HttpResponseMessage RefreshAccessToken()
    {
        return FetchTokens(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
            { "refresh_token", _sessionService.GetRefreshToken() }
        });
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Builds and returns a string representative of the provider's authorization URI.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri GetAuthorizationUri()
    {
        return new Uri(
            new Uri(_appSettings.Value.AuthBaseUri), "authorization" +
            "?client_id=" + _appSettings.Value.AuthClientId +
            "&response_type=code" + 
            "&redirect_uri=" + _appSettings.Value.AuthRedirectUri
        );
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the session contains an access token.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAuthenticated()
    {
        return (_sessionService.GetAccessToken() != null);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Destroys the access/refresh tokens stored in the session.
    /// </summary>
    public void LogOut()
    {
        _sessionService.ClearTokens();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes a string as Base64.
    /// </summary>
    private static string Base64Encode(string plainText) 
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you use `ISessionService`?

Comment: What do you mean? I use it in the class above which is the implementation of the four methods laid out in the interface.

Comment: I mean where do you inject `ISessionService` and call `GetAccessToken` or `SetTokens`. You might be calling it at some point where no HTTP context is available.

Comment: Oh ok I see. `SetTokens()` is called for the `AuthenticationService` which is also setup in `Startup.cs` and is used in the `AuthenticationController` to load the initial page. So HTTP context should be full and well setup by then. `TryGetString()` is called within the `SessionService` and nowhere else. So if I'm able to store successfully in `SessionService` before `TrGetString()` is called then the values should be there.

Comment: Where do you call `GetAccessToken`?

Comment: That's also in the `AuthenticationService`. It's a very small project. I can edit and post the `AuthenticationService` file or upload this project onto GitHub and link if that can further help?

Comment: When debugging and viewing the Session ID, shouldn't that ID value be the same? If they are different then those are different Session instances?

Comment: You can add the code to the opening post.

Comment: Might there be any place where `IAuthenticationService` or any other service which calls `IAuthenticationService` is used where a HTTP context is not available?

Comment: You're pretty much seeing most of the project there. There's another controller and service but that only deals with calling the API endpoints once authentication is verified using the valid tokens from the authorizing process shown above. So I'd say no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173502/discussion-between-daniel-jackson-and-henk-mollema).

Comment: So I created a test service and am storing in that session. It looks like those variables are saving until I try and use the endpoints like the Auth endpoint where a user is brought to a login page. It seems like that's clearing out the session store. I didn't put this project on a repo because it's using my private API keys. I could GitIgnore the appsettings.json but no one would be able to run the app anyways.

Comment: So it seems like session storage won't work here which is strange because it's suggested by the company.

Comment: It's just weird because a lot of the stuff I'm reading is saying to use session to store between page refreshes. But it's not persisting for me.